# Click handler on v-for loop in vue3 not showing up in the DOM

Tags: vuejs3

I have run into a roadblock on a project where everything seems to be working fine except that I can't seem to add a click handler on a v-for loop object.

Here's the demo code that is structured very similarly to my original code

```
<template>
  <article>
    <a
      v-for="(post, index) in posts"
      :key="index"
      target="_blank"
       @click="alert(post.title)"
    >
      <figure >
        <img
          :src="post.source_url"
          :alt="post.title"
        />
        <figcaption>{{ (post.title) }}</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </article>
</template>

<script setup>

const  posts = [
  {
    title:"abc",
    content:"defg",
    source_url:"https://unsplash.it/200/100",
    
  },
  {
    title:"uvw",
    content:"xyz",
    source_url:"https://unsplash.it/150/101",
    
  }
]


</script>
```

Here's the link to codepen as well..
https://codepen.io/alimbolar/pen/XWBzgVX

The console.log shows this error on codepen..

```
"[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler" "
" " at <Pen>"
```

but on my original code there's no error on localhost.. it's just that the click handler is just not appearing in the dom..

I would appreciate some guidance on what I am doing wrong as I seem to have tried everything and I know maybe it's something very very basic that I am missing.. please advise.

Regards,
Alim

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a ref to wrap the posts array to make it reactive? `const  posts = ref([....])` after importing ref, of course.

Comment: Also, Change `@click="alert(post.title)"` to `@click="myOwnMethod(post.title)"` and then call the alert inside of your own method.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a warning.  The real error is given in the console right after:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.alert is not a function
```

The context of inline handlers is not the same as `window`.  You need to call the alert function from a method in your component script.

```js
@click="showAlert(post.title)"
```

```js
const showAlert = (title) => { 
  alert(title) 
}
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/ZEjayNO)

Comment: Got it...:-).. so basically I need to call a method or function in the event handler (which makes sense) but can you explain why this does not work in the same way : `@click="()=>{alert(post.title)}"` I was expecting it to work but it didn't seem to..

Comment: Arrow functions do work in template code, but it still won't provide you the `window` API because arrow functions are always bound to the parent context, and as we've established, Vue's template does not provide `window` which is where the `alert` function comes from.  I suppose if really desired you can [add window as a global property](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next-webpack-preview/issues/15) to your app and access it in the template that way